# How to enable a new language in Osclass

Tags: osclass

I have installed a new language in back end. And also enabled in back end. Now EN & ES is active in back end.
How can I see ES in front end? Still It is displaying content in EN. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the front end ya new option should appear to change the language

Comment: You are right. I have one doubt. I'm getting No file was uploaded alert while import a mail.sql in import data under tools. Do you know why this error occur?